# Empty setup project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, installation, custom-action

I have a ClickOnce installation I want to distribute. Some system administrators prefer a MSI installation package which, when run, installs the ClickOnce application.

I've created a Visual Studio 2008 Setup project which references a single assembly where I've implemented a custom action. The custom action can install the ClickOnce application, and that works fine.

My problem is that after the installation has completed, the customer now has a folder named C:\Program Files\Company\SetupName which contains the custom action assembly.

I would like that after the installation, no files are left behind on the users system under C:\Program Files. Is there a way to accomplish this?

It's possible to get rid of the question asking the user where he wants to install the software, simply by removing that step in the wizard from the "User interfaces" list, but the software will still be installed into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

MSI installer and Clickonce application are not compatible...  lock at this.. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/DDayUpdate_Part1.aspx